# Riemann manifolds and Levi-Civita connection

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M, \langle.,.\rangle )$ be a 2-dimensional Riemannian manifold, $\nabla$ its Levi-Civita connection. How can I show that there is a function $K \in \mathscr C^{\infty}(M)$ such that $$R^{\nabla}(X,Y)Z=K(\langle Y,Z\rangle X-\langle X,Z \rangle Y) $$ for all $X,Y,Z \in \Gamma (TM)$?

Would appreciate some help or approach to solve this, thanks in advance.

Comment: You could do this in a purely linear-algebra way: compute the dimension of the space of curvature-like tensors over a vector space of dimension 2.

Comment: The problem with questions like this is that we have absolutely no idea what you know and what you don't, what your tools are, etc. For surfaces, there's only one sectional curvature at each point, as there's only one $2$-dimensional subspace of the tangent plane.